# Can we call firebase as a server?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, client-server, android-architecture, 2-tier

I am using firebase for storing data through android application. I want to architecture diagram for that application, so can I call the firebase as a server? I am trying to use client server architecture, so for the server, I write firebase as server. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you use Firebase Realtime Database in your app, I'd indeed either visualize it as a server or as a database.

I find the latter especially useful if you still want to explain the nature of the app talking directly to a cloud-hosted database. Visualizing it as a server makes it easier to brush over that, so is a good option in cases where that is needed.

Comment: I am using firebase just for storing/fetching the data and authentication purpose. Can I still name it that the database (Firebase Realtime database) I am using is provided by Firebase Server? And am I interacting with the server or directly with the Firebase Realtime database?

Comment: Most databases act like servers these days, including non-cloud hosted ones such as SQL Server, Postgresql and MySQL. So they're both databases and servers. How you visualize them depends more on your needs for the diagram than anything else. There is no "right" or "wrong" here, only determining what fits your needs.